# Network interface's configured DNS server is not used when domain name is resolved

Tags: windows-10, dns

I have configured the DNS server of all the interfaces as 1.1.1.1. However, `Resolve-DnsName` and `nslookup` do not use `1.1.1.1` unless I explicitly specified as below:

```
C:\> Resolve-DnsName sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net -Server 1.1.1.1

Name                   Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                   ----   ---   -------    ---------
sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net   AAAA   1592  Answer     2606:2800:247:1cb7:261b:1f9c:2074:3c
sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net   A      2916  Answer     152.199.39.108
```

When I don't explicitly specify the DNS server:

```
C:\> resolve-dnsname sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net

Name                    Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                    ----   ---   -------    ---------
sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net    AAAA   86312 Answer     ::1
sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net    A      86312 Answer     127.0.0.1
```

Current settings:

```
C:\> Get-DnsClientServerAddress

InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
Ethernet                            22 IPv4    {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}
Ethernet                            22 IPv6    {fe80::9628:6fff:feb3:2433, fe80::9628:6fff:feb3:2433}
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1 IPv4    {}
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1          1 IPv6    {}
vEthernet (Default Switch)          38 IPv4    {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}
vEthernet (Default Switch)          38 IPv6    {}
vEthernet (WSL)                     45 IPv4    {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}
vEthernet (WSL)                     45 IPv6    {}
```

I would expect the domain to be resolved into 152.199.39.108 even when the `-Server` argument is not used.

Just to give more context, I am having issue installing `winget` packages because `winget` cannot connect to the package source which is `sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net`

***EDIT 1:***

I did more experiments as below. It is my ISP's DNS server that resolves the name to 127.0.0.1. But still, the question is, why is 1.1.1.1 dns server not used?

```
$ ipconfig /flushdns

$ Resolve-DnsName sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net -CacheOnly
Resolve-DnsName: sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net : DNS record does not exist.

$ Resolve-DnsName sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net -NoHostsFile

<still 127.0.01>

$ Resolve-DnsName sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net -Type NS

Name       : dns.<my-isp-provider>.com
QueryType  : A
TTL        : 37238
Section    : Additional
IP4Address : <ips-provider-ip>

$ Resolve-DnsName sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net -server <ips-provider-ip> -Type A

<still 127.0.01>
```

Comment: Have you installed a proxy ?

Comment: @harrymc No, I don't use any proxy

Comment: Try A: `Resolve-DnsName -NoHostsFile sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net` and/or check if there's anything in your local hosts file, B: DNS cache (which you can clear or query directly with `-CacheOnly`), or C: does the current local hostname match your query, since you're getting `127.0.0.1` back? See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order-dae00cc9-7e9c-c0cc-8360-477b99cb978a for the order of resolution

Comment: Thanks @Cpt.Whale. I tried your suggestions. Still have no answer to my question. But they give me some hints. Please see EDIT 1.

Comment: To be clear: `sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net` is **not** the name of the computer you're running this on (or of your WSL?). Because this is the expected output when using the hostname, like `Resolve-DnsName localhost` will always return 127.0.0.1 and ::1 without checking a DNS server. Otherwise, what Server name/IP does `nslookup` show if you don't specify one? Or if you do `nslookup;set debug;sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net`

Comment: `sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net` is definitely not the name of any of my computers. After a night leaving the computer running, both `nslookup;set debug;sni1gl.wpc.nucdn.net` and `Resolve-Dns` now gives me the correct IP. `Resolve-Dns <name> -server <my_isp_dns_server>` still gives `127.0.0.1`. This means the configured `1.1.1.1` is picked up. Although this issue is resolved now. I still don't know why. Maybe because of one of the commands I ran in EDIT 1?

Comment: You have a link-local IPv6 resolver configured on “Ethernet”. It’s highly likely this is the one Windows is querying. Is this perhaps a Pi-Hole or anything the like?